# Rails route to specific action for resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to get the url for given params:

```
url_for({
  :action => "show",
  :controller => "questions",
  :dashboard_id => "123",
  :dashboard_type => "mono",
  :question_id => "1234",
  :only_path => true
})
```

But I get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"questions", :dashboard_id=>"123", :dashboard_type=>"mono", :question_id=>"1234"}
```

In my `routes.rb` file, I have this configuration:

```
resources :dashboards, :only => [:index, :all, :create] do
  resources :questions, :path => '/:dashboard_type/questions'
end
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: also post result of rake routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `:question_id` with `:id`

It should be

```
url_for({
  :action => "show",
  :controller => "questions",
  :dashboard_id => "123",
  :dashboard_type => "mono",
  :id => "1234",
  :only_path => true
})
```

As there is no `:question_id`

```
dashboard_question GET    /dashboards/:dashboard_id/:dashboard_type/questions/:id(.:format)      questions#show
```